# Carto JS only gets cartodb_id on click

Tags: carto, carto-js

Here's my code:

```
        function main() {
            // create leaflet map and define some properties
            var map=    L.map(
                "map",
                {
                    zoomControl: true,
                    center: [40,-95],
                    zoom: 4
                }
            );

            // add a base layer to map
            var Hydda_Full = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: 'Tiles courtesy of <a href="http://openstreetmap.se/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap Sweden</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
            });
            Hydda_Full.addTo(map);

            // viz.json of map
            var layerURL=           "https://CARTO_USERNAME.carto.com/api/v2/viz/CARTO_ID/viz.json";

            // add CARTO layer with on layer
            cartodb.createLayer(map, layerURL, {infowindow: false, tooltip: false})
                .addTo(map)
                .done(function(layer){
                    layer.setInteraction(true);

                    layer.on("featureClick",function(e, latlng, pos, data){
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                    });
        }

        window.onload = main;
```

`console.log(data)` prints an object with only the `cartodb_id` key and its value. But the dataset on which my Carto map is based has way more columns than `cartodb_id`.

Why do I only get the `cartodb_id` column, not the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because columns are defined when [setting interactivity](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/api-methods#sublayersetinteractivitycartodbid-name-), different than [setInteraction](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/api-methods#sublayersetinteractiontrue) - try this:

```
.on('done', function(layer) {

   var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0); //which sublayer depends on your viz.json

   sublayer.set({ 'interactivity': ['cartodb_id', 'your_column_name'] });

   sublayer.setInteraction(true);

   sublayer.on("featureClick",function(e, latlng, pos, data){
      console.log(data);
   });

})
```

Comment: It works, thanks. How can I get a list of all column names so I don't have to copy and paste them all from Carto?

Comment: `var colNames = [];
var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);
var colQuery = "SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'your_account_name' AND table_name = 'your_table_name'"

$.getJSON('https://your_account_name.carto.com/api/v2/sql/?q=' + colQuery + '&api_key=your_api_key', function(data) {
  $.each(data.rows, function(key,val) {
    colNames.push(JSON.stringify(val.column_name));
  });
  console.log("colNames = " + colNames);
});`

Comment: @Username be careful with that SQL query, It is useful, but I believe it will also return any deleted column names as well. I've started using `SELECT attname::text as column_name
    FROM   pg_attribute
    WHERE  attrelid = 'your_table_name'::regclass
    AND    attnum > 0
    AND    NOT attisdropped
    ORDER  BY attnum;`