# Sending carto a SQL API request for column names returns error

Tags: postgresql, carto

I got a [tip](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247531/carto-js-only-gets-cartodb-id-on-click/247549?noredirect=1#comment390574_247549) from a previous question for getting a list of column names in a Carto table.

I enter this into my browser: `https://MY_CARTO_USERNAME.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q‌​=SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema = 'MY_CARTO_USERNAME' AND table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'&api_key=MY_API_KEY`. Of course, I replace `MY_CARTO_USERNAME` and `MY_API_KEY` with my Carto username and API key.

This is the error I get: `{"error":["You must indicate a sql query"]}`

What must I change in my query to get the column names of my Carto table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace the white spaces with `+`. I think this is the cause of your problem. Also, `table_schema` is not needed. This query works for me:

```
https://USER_NAME.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q=SELECT+column_name+FROM+information_schema.columns+WHERE+table_name+=+'TABLE_NAME'&api_key=API_KEY
```